# What does the ^= operator do in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am searching in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) what the ^= assigment operator does.

The only thing I could find so far is:

> Other assignment operators work similarly. The following are recognized:
>
> ```
>   **=    +=    *=    &=    &.=    <<=    
>    -=    /=    |=    |.=   >>=    ||=
>    .=    %=    ^=    ^.=   //=    &&=
> ```

What is the result of `$c ^= $r;`?

Comment: It is syntactic sugar for **xor operator** `$xor_sum = $xor_sum ^ $i;` can be written as `$xor_sum ^= $i;`

Comment: @AbhiNickz ah, it is the assignment version of the bitwise ^ operator. Thanks! Please add as answer.

Comment: Comment Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Perl `^=` is a **syntactic sugar** for **xor operator**

```
$xor_sum = $xor_sum ^ $i;
```

can be rewritten as

```
$xor_sum ^= $i;
```

Answer (score 3):

Any time you see a Perl expression of the form:

```
$l op= $r;
```

It can be rewritten as:

```
$l = $l op $r;
```

(Ok, I say "any time", but there are probably exceptions. There are always exceptions in Perl. But I can't think of one right now.)